# Google Keyboard 'remove suggestion' not working

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, keyboard, gboard

I'm having an annoying issue with the Google Keyboard app on Android 6.0 (and on an HTC One M9 if that matters).

I like to be able to remove erroneous suggested words by long pressing on them and dragging them into the 'remove suggestion' trash can. That used to work fine, but recently when I do it nothing changes - the word is not removed, and keeps being suggested. I'm not entirely sure when this behaviour started. It was certainly after I upgraded from an HTC One M8 to an M9. But I can't remember whether it ever worked on the M9.

I've looked through the settings many times over, and searched Google for a solution, but I can't find anything of help.

If you can offer any advice that would be great. Ideally I'd really like to keep my personal dictionary intact, if possible.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

On Gboard v7 (Nougat) I've noticed that this long press and drag gesture doesn't work in chrome but seems to be working as expected in Messengers such as WhatsApp. Give that a try